# Connect pandas output to excel sheet via ODBC

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

The query below does the following: Connect to a SQL Server db via ODBC, run a SQL script (many queries separated by ";"), create two dataframes for two specific query results, and then export them to two tabs within an excel workbook:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import time

name= 'ouput' + str(time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime()))
print ("Connecting via ODBC")

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Server DB Prod', autocommit=True)

print ("Connected!\n")

inputdir = 'H:\\Queries\\ADS'

#for script in os.listdir(inputdir):
with open(inputdir+'\\' + 'query' +'.sql','r') as inserts:
    sqlScript = inserts.read()
    for statement in sqlScript.split(';'):
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(statement)

query1="Select * from #leadership"
data1=pd.read_sql_query(query1, conn).sort_values(['channel','terr_code'], ascending=[0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)
#print(data1.head(n=100))
query2="Select * from #ml"
data2=pd.read_sql_query(query2, conn).sort_values(['channel','terr_code','client_name'], ascending=[0,1,1]).reset_index(drop=True)

print('query finished')
conn.close()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name+ '.xlsx')
data1.to_excel(writer,'Leadership Summary')
data2.to_excel(writer,'ML Detail')
writer.save()

print("Results were succesfully exported")
```

However, I am hoping to instead be able to connect to an existing excel file via ODBC in order to update the tabs of my workbook dynamically and not lose the formatting and graphs- to allow real automation. Any other solution that would allow the same will certainly work.

Background: I am trying to automate a process where I run a query in SQL Server (via Python), and have the output update the tabs of an existing excel worksheet- I was thinking by connecting via ODBC. That worksheet has specific formatting, and formulas+graphs built based on the data.

Note: I dont have write permission, only read, so I cant connect a "final" SQL table to excel via ODBC. I am doing some additional data blending from other sources in Python (not shown), so connecting a SQL query to excel via ODBC will not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best strategy is to access the Excel workbook and use its facilities instead of external tools in order to leave all other objects untouched. Hence, consider the `win32com` client where you can then access the Excel object library such as its [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel) method.

And instead of `pyodbc` as database API, use Window's [ADODB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524771(v=vs.90).aspx) API which can use ODBC connections. Also, there is no need for `pandas` as worksheet objects are used to hold data. NOTE: this solution only works on Windows machines.

```
import win32com.client as win32

try:
    # INITIALIZE OBJECTS
    xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    ado_conn = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('ADODB.Connection')
    ado_rst = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('ADODB.Recordset')

    # OPEN CONNECTION
    ado_conn.Open('DSN=Server DB Prod')

    # RUN QUERIES
    with open(inputdir+'\\' + 'query' +'.sql','r') as inserts:
        sqlScript = inserts.read()
        for statement in sqlScript.split(';'):
            ado_conn.Execute(statement)

    # OPEN WORKBOOK AND UPDATE SHEETS
    xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Full\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx')

    ls = xlwb.Worksheets('Leadership Summary') 
    ls.Cells.ClearContents()
    ado_rst.Open("Select * from #leadership", ado_conn)
    for i in range(ado_rst.Fields.Count):
       ls.Cells(1, i+1).Value = ado_rst.Fields(i).Name     # COLUMNS
    ls.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset(ado_rst)              # DATA ROWS
    ado_rst.Close()

    ml = xlwb.Worksheets('ML Detail')
    ml.Cells.ClearContents()
    ado_rst.Open("Select * from #ml", ado_conn)         
    for i in range(ado_rst.Fields.Count): 
       ml.Cells(1, i+1).Value = ado_rst.Fields(i).Name     # COLUMNS
    ml.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset(ado_rst)              # DATA ROWS
    ado_rst.Close()

    ado_conn.Close()
    xlapp.Visible = True        # OPENS WORKBOOK WITH ABOVE CHANGES TO SCREEN

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    # RELEASE RESOURCES
    ls = None; ml = None
    ado_rst = None; ado_conn = None
    xlwb = None; xlapp = None
```

*Hopefully, this debunks any who think VBA (also a COM-interfaced language) is the only coding language for Excel!*

Comment: I get an error "'int' object is not callable" but no mention of the row the error occurred on. It's definitely not the SQL script because it runs just fine as per the version I presented.. Any idea?
Also, "Hopefully, this debunks any who think VBA (also a COM-interfaced language) is the only coding language for Excel!". What type of sorcery is that?

Comment: It came down to how columns was being written. `.Count()` and `.Name()` are not callable so should have parentheses removed as `.Count` and `.Name`. See edit.

Comment: You were right- it ran successfully. Thank you!. 2 issues though: #1 I changed A2 in your query to B8, which is where the data begins to write. However the headers still populated in row 1 (A1 and on). Is there any way to not populate headers? #2 ClearContents removes all data from the tab. However, I have data that I'd like to keep in rows 1:7, where row 7 is the headers with specific formatting. Any way to specify what I'd like to keep/remove? Thanks alot!

Comment: In both column loops, simply move the [.Cells(row, column)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel) if you know your Excel objects which would be `.Cells(7, 2)` which corresponds to `B7`. So in loop `.Cells(7, i+2).Value`. And remove the `ClearContents` line but do note previous *longer* queries' last few rows may remain if new *shorter* query replaces it.

Comment: Awesome! And instead of removing ClearContents I used ls.Range("B8:Z1000000").ClearContents() to specify the range I want cleared. Is there a way to only write the data, without the column headers? This would be the last thing I need for this masterpiece. pywin32 functionality is definitely really cool

Comment: Sorry one last thing- it looks like it dropped the concept of sorting (compared to my query). Any way to get that back?

Comment: I am not understanding. Just run an `ORDER BY` in SQL statements.

Comment: That's present in my query, but it comes into excel out of order. That's why I had the pandas sort commands

Comment: I can't recreate issue. It might be due to using #temp tables. Try sorting where they are created, possibly in text file list of SQL commands. Otherwise look into Excel's [Range.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. No luck with removing headers- any chance you can assist? If I remove for i, I have an issue with ls.Cells(8, i+2).Value = ado_rst.Fields(i).Name

Comment: Adding "order by" into ado_rst.Open took care of the ordering actually. Your answer should be pinned- I am seeing countless inquires using pandas.ExcelWriter, your way is far better- though it has a windows dependency

Comment: What if I wanted another tab of the excel file to be written from a non SQL query? I additionally call an API then export it into csv currently; is there a way to use this functionality to either write the output of the API into one of the tabs within the excel file, or if not directly from the API- from the csv (or txt) file it produces?

Comment: On Windows you can ODBC connect to [text files](https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/) where the data source is the folder path: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed";`. You can even ODBC connect to the [Excel workbooks](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) and use same `CopyFromRecordset` process.